# Cannot load PS script from a C# program, as scripts are disabled on system, Scope set to Bypass

Tags: c#, powershell

So I have look at several post here and on other sites But even after changing Executionpolicy to RemoteSigened I still get the error, I have even tried with Bypass on MachinePolicy and enabled scripts to run in group policies.

[image]

I found this example [Passing PowerShell parameter with C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a0c26de-fa2d-498e-94ff-eec33e6ef42c/passing-powershell-parameter-with-c) I get the following error when i try to Invoke.

System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: 'File Path\TestADUser.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.%27)

```
    public string Test()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string script = @"Path\TestADUser.ps1";
        var FirstName = "Test1234";
        PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.AddCommand(script, false);
        shell.AddParameter("FirstName", FirstName);
        Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();
        Collection<ErrorRecord> errors = shell.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ErrorRecord error in errors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(result.ToString());
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

TestADUser.ps1

```
param(
[parameter(position=0)]
[string]$FirstName)
##Output
Write-Output $FirstName
```

Comment: `RemoteSigned` still requires the scripts to be signed. Try `Unrestricted` Also, you need to set it for both x64 and x86 powershell versions.

Comment: I have tried setting LocalMachine & CurrentUser to Unrestricted in both x64 and x86. I get the following. System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: 'File TestADUser.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more... and 
Inner Exception 
UnauthorizedAccessException: File TestADUser.ps1cannot be loaded.....

Comment: You should add that info to your question.